# php image upload problem with move_uploaded_file function

Tags: php, image-uploading

i have one image upload script 
which upload same image on two locations same time with move_uploaded_file() function like this

```
  $fpath="../p/e/".$prop_fac1;
  $error = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $fpath);

  $fpath1="../p/t/".$prop_fac1;
  $error1 = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $fpath1);
```

the problem is, first part works mean it upload files to ../p/e but not copy file to second location...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problem is, first part works mean it upload files to ../p/e but not copy file to second location...

Works as designed. The file is **moved**, not copied. Use [`copy()`](http://www.php.net/copy) for the second command, using the target path from the first one.

```
 $error1 = copy($fpath, $fpath1);
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be because it's MOVE_uploaded_file, not COPY_uploaded_file. What you need to do is:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $fpath);
copy($fpath, $fpath1);
```